# How to use local scope inside useEffect hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, scope

The following code works fine:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const apiService = new APIClient('api address');
  var topicCommentsReq = new GetTopicDetailsRequest();
  topicCommentsReq.setTopicCid(Buffer.from("123", "hex"));
  apiService.getTopicDetails(topicCommentsReq, {}, function (err, response) {
    console.log(`response : ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
  });
}
```

I want to convert this callback style function to async/await style, so i did something like this:

```ts
const promisifyFn =
  (fn: Function) =>
  (...args: any[]) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      return fn(...args, (err: Error, data: any) => {
        return err ? reject(err) : resolve(data);
      });
    });

useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const apiService = new APIClient("api address");
    const topicCommentsReq = new GetTopicDetailsRequest();
    topicCommentsReq.setTopicCid(Buffer.from("123", "hex"));
    const getTopicDetails = promisifyFn(apiService.getTopicDetails);
    try {
      const res = await getTopicDetails(topicCommentsReq, {});
      console.log(`response : ${JSON.stringify(res)}`);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  })();
});
```

The following error message shows up:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'client_')
 if (callback !== undefined) {
      return this.client_.rpcCall(
        this.hostname_ +
          '/StelaPlatform.GRPC.API/GetTopicDetails',
        request,
        metadata || {},
        this.methodDescriptorGetTopicDetails,
        callback);
    }
```

My guess is this problem related with the lcoal scope. When the function run inside async function, the this scope is different. But how should I resolve this issue in general?

Comment: An effect hook with no dependency array runs on **every render**. Is that what you want to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in passing the function reference to `apiService.getTopicDetails`, it loses its `this` context.

In order to keep the prototype function in its prototype, you should use either an arrow function...

```ts
const getTopicDetails = promisifyFn((...args) =>
  apiService.getTopicDetails(...args));
```

or [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

```ts
const getTopicDetails = promisifyFn(apiService.getTopicDetails.bind(apiService));
```